# Number of samples to predict the next number in a pseudorandom number generator

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, random

Let:

$$R_{n+1} = (mR_n + b) \bmod{a} $$

Assume we know the values of $R_1, R_2, \ldots, R_L $. What is the minimum value of $L$ (if it exists) such that we can determine $R_0, m, b$ and $a$?

Comment: For $L$ sufficiently big, we may assume that $a\approx \max\{R_i\}+\min\{R_i\}$. We will also observe cases with $d:=R_i-R_j$ relatively small. Then $R_{i+1}-R_{j+1}\equiv md\pmod a$ is quite a good crib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking in the worst case if $R_0=0,m=b=1$ then we cannot determine $a$ until we complete a cycle.

Practically speaking, though, $L=3$ is always too small but $L=4$ may be enough. For $L=3$ we have
$$
\begin{align}
\left[\begin{matrix}
R_1 & 1 \\ R_2 & 1
\end{matrix}\right]
\left[\begin{matrix}m\\ b\end{matrix}\right] & 
\equiv \left[\begin{matrix} R_2 \\ R_3\end{matrix}\right] \\
\left[\begin{matrix}m\\ b\end{matrix}\right] & 
\equiv \left[\begin{matrix}
R_1 & 1 \\ R_2 & 1
\end{matrix}\right]^{-1}\left[\begin{matrix} R_2 \\ R_3\end{matrix}\right]
\end{align}
$$
and the matrix inverse can be computed modulo most $a$.

[Here's essentially the same question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4268/cracking-a-linear-congruential-generator) on security.SE, with a solution giving this algorithm.
Define $t_n=R_{n+1}-R_n$, then
$$
\begin{align}
t_n &\equiv (m-1)R_n+b \\
t_{n+1} &\equiv (m-1)mR_n+mb \\
t_{n+2} &\equiv (m-1)m^2R_n+m^2b\\
t_nt_{n+2}-t_{n+1}^2 &\equiv 0 \pmod{a}
\end{align}
$$
Define $u_n=|t_nt_{n+2}-t_{n+1}^2|$ then $a=\gcd(u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_k)$ with probability increasing in $k$.

For example, if we are given
$$
4722,6543,8671,1692,2457,7536
$$
then $u_1=7\cdot 11\cdot 23\cdot 9733$. We can compute $u_2,u_3$ and find $\gcd(u_1,u_2,u_3)=9733$ which is prime and must be $a$.

Or in this case we can determine the unique solution without using $R_6$ by computing $m,b$ for each factor of $u_1$ that is larger than our largest sample. This gives eight possibilities, e.g. $(a,m,b)=(9733,541,1987)$ or $(749441,175735,566501)$, but only the first also matches $R_4$ and $R_5$.