# determining the next random number pseudorandom number generator?

Tags: sequences-and-series, random, cryptography

I have given 3 numbers let's say basic example `x_0=5, x_1=6 and x_2=2` and modulus `p is 7`,

`x_n=(ax_n-1+c)modp where p=7`, I am trying to generate linear equations to solve but I am kind of lost

I do this

```
6=(a5+c)mod7 therefore 7*x+7=5a+c 
2=(6a+c)mod7 therefore 7*y+2=6a+c
```

now I can subtract them and have 3 unknown x,y and a but two equations to solve,

I do not understand how to generate two equations with two unknows

I really appreciate your help

I read this but I could not understand

[Number of samples to predict the next number in a pseudorandom number generator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449621/number-of-samples-to-predict-the-next-number-in-a-pseudorandom-number-generator)

Answer (score 0):

If you start from $$5a+c \equiv 6 \pmod 7$$ $$ 6a+c \equiv 2 \pmod 7$$ then you can solve these in a similar way to ordinary simultaneous equations. Here subtraction gives $$a \equiv 2-6 \equiv 3 \pmod 7$$ and so substituting into the first equivalence $$c \equiv 6-5\times 3 \equiv 5 \pmod 7$$

You can check that $x_n\equiv 3x_{n-1}+ 5 \pmod 7$ for your initial values.  The full cycle is $5,6,2,4,3,0,5,\ldots$ while $1$ is a fixed point